# Digitally sign with HSM Thales payShield 8000

Tags: digital-signature, hsm

I am very new with HSM and now I have to use HSM payShield 8000 to sign PDF files by commands. Someone can help me to show me all steps (with commands) I have to do from beginning?

Everything I have done till now is generate LMK (GK), but when I use EI to generate key pair, it shows error 17. I am not sure that I have done/understood right or not.

Thanks so much.

Comment: For HSM, you require HSM driver (.dll or .so). Which programming language/platform your are using? for signing pdf, you require pdf component... The question you had asked has vast scope, there is no 1 page code to do this...

Comment: I do not have .dll or .so files, that's why I am trying to do this stuff by host command. I am just asking for steps with only command codes I have to follow.

Answer (score 0):

Error 17 indicates that the HSM is not in authorised state. Authorised state can be set via the console or remote manager

EI is sent as follows:

```
00000000: 48 45 41 44 45 49 30 32  30 34 38 30 32 23 30 30  HEADEI0204802#00
00000010: 30 30                                             00
```

EJ Response:

```
00000000: 48 45 41 44 45 4A 30 30  30 82 01 0A 02 82 01 01  HEADEJ000.......
00000010: 00 AB 28 3B 82 DB AF 50  96 1A 9C FA 9A 2D 93 B4  ..(;...P.....-..
00000020: D8 4A 39 AA 4A 7E D8 CC  A3 8A 49 86 43 1D 69 3B  .J9.J~....I.C.i;
00000030: FC 5C B9 C3 9F C8 66 4C  90 B5 56 10 F3 8D 59 CB  .\....fL..V...Y.
00000040: 06 CA A9 9D 49 64 F5 77  E4 8F 2E 8B B7 A9 BE A3  ....Id.w........
00000050: C8 78 6B 6A 5F 55 C1 43  CC DE E1 12 58 AB A3 96  .xkj_U.C....X...
00000060: F2 A0 3B AB E3 A3 57 99  51 69 18 EE F9 C8 B1 61  ..;...W.Qi.....a
00000070: 08 9B 2F 46 FD 90 D7 53  1B 49 E3 9D 01 38 BE BD  ../F...S.I...8..
00000080: A3 0E 55 DB 9E 25 0A 6A  CC 3C 71 9B F0 E1 FC 29  ..U..%.j.<q....)
00000090: 1C DE 3A 03 48 36 2E E6  85 9D 7C A5 57 51 B1 78  ..:.H6....|.WQ.x
000000A0: 23 6D 50 BE EC A9 CC 66  6F 5F 6F 0A 29 82 BA 6C  #mP....fo_o.)..l
000000B0: 17 A7 54 EF 1C B0 82 80  52 AB F4 7F 13 D7 6E B9  ..T.....R.....n.
000000C0: F1 02 5D 36 95 27 8B BE  9F 57 77 8E 39 A2 1C B8  ..]6.'...Ww.9...
000000D0: 92 C6 E1 73 80 C8 52 92  22 3C 43 6D A0 DF 06 A2  ...s..R."<Cm....
000000E0: 5D 73 85 AD 11 96 17 E7  C1 C9 0B 33 31 FC 6A D1  ]s.........31.j.
000000F0: AB 4B 26 85 32 FB E4 F5  65 72 0E A0 51 FE 52 A5  .K&.2...er..Q.R.
00000100: 7C A2 5B 99 C4 8F BF 8F  D6 38 93 03 79 48 5E F9  |.[......8..yH^.
00000110: 8B 02 03 01 00 01 46 46  46 46 53 31 30 37 30 34  ......FFFFS10704
00000120: 30 33 52 53 30 30 4E 30  30 30 32 4A 5E 63 A3 A3  03RS00N0002J^c..
00000130: E5 C7 74 F2 61 C8 A7 21  3D 2A DE 57 D0 03 5B 56  ..t.a..!=*.W..[V
00000140: 2E 4C 52 41 1F EE 6C 99  F1 88 58 89 BC 5E 42 18  .LRA..l...X..^B.
00000150: 91 DE A8 28 88 52 E3 64  58 66 30 4B 10 B8 B4 3E  ...(.R.dXf0K...>
00000160: AE C5 38 FE A0 D2 67 FC  D4 BE A9 7E A1 8E E5 D4  ..8...g....~....
00000170: DC 57 EB 73 4E F5 27 3B  31 1B 1B 64 4C B3 9B 43  .W.sN.';1..dL..C
00000180: 1A C0 4E 66 C8 43 EF FC  B8 6B E9 52 EF D7 4D 7E  ..Nf.C...k.R..M~
00000190: DB 3D 6A 92 08 E5 A2 6D  47 D7 88 26 A6 3E CD EA  .=j....mG..&.>..
000001A0: 89 77 68 3E 37 AC C1 45  F5 9D 30 36 A2 84 39 AC  .wh>7..E..06..9.
000001B0: 01 15 DA D9 AF 19 FA AE  0D 08 90 ED 06 3C 60 2D  .............<`-
000001C0: 79 ED 66 0B BF 9B F1 02  A0 89 4E C4 58 29 77 85  y.f.......N.X)w.
000001D0: 95 94 96 64 16 5F F2 6E  95 CB 61 FD AB F2 81 81  ...d._.n..a.....
000001E0: 42 C4 F4 BC 86 1C 1F 37  9C 06 E9 D5 57 81 DA 8F  B......7....W...
000001F0: C9 EA 66 28 36 D7 AF AC  53 A9 BD 61 35 12 53 D1  ..f(6...S..a5.S.
00000200: 0D 3D 68 73 8A 6E BE 36  19 58 77 DA FF 9E CA 56  .=hs.n.6.Xw....V
00000210: 9D BC C2 18 0A 66 12 54  E0 48 2B 34 57 09 00 92  .....f.T.H+4W...
00000220: 34 F0 FD 63 C6 BD 78 2A  D2 24 59 C2 8A AB CB D5  4..c..x*.$Y.....
00000230: 77 6F 0C 72 94 B4 D3 2F  F5 3E C3 8C 61 DC 80 2F  wo.r.../.>..a../
00000240: D1 85 DD EE E4 F8 11 5C  C9 D6 D2 66 B7 49 4E 8D  .......\...f.IN.
00000250: 6F AA A3 CE F8 B0 22 A7  F9 24 2C C4 3D 89 03 DB  o....."..$,.=...
00000260: 16 52 FC B3 1C 7A 50 7A  43 6F 84 80 F2 36 31 16  .R...zPzCo...61.
00000270: BB 61 68 FA E2 53 13 F1  65 7C F5 BF 69 A9 0D 45  .ah..S..e|..i..E
00000280: E8 6B 81 1F 1F ED F1 0B  56 10 CD F4 56 1C D2 7D  .k......V...V..}
00000290: 3E AC DE B7 43 BA 11 D4  AB 6F 69 8A DC 56 38 34  >...C....oi..V84
000002A0: EA 39 37 D7 02 91 64 94  37 B3 B7 F1 88 FC 27 BE  .97...d.7.....'.
000002B0: B0 85 46 BE E3 B5 D4 33  5B 22 47 2C 65 39 CA E7  ..F....3["G,e9..
000002C0: 6B E6 CA F7 48 9B 65 97  96 CE E7 0E 31 5B 87 E8  k...H.e.....1[..
000002D0: 46 4A 20 DB 8C B1 8D 4D  36 71 40 E1 B6 5B D3 0C  FJ ....M6q@..[..
000002E0: E4 DE 3E FB 1F C6 20 2B  D5 9E 23 0F DE A5 08 BD  ..>... +..#.....
000002F0: 6C EE 13 0B B6 31 38 02  CA 0A D3 B8 7A 61 48 17  l....18.....zaH.
00000300: 3D 65 BF 2C 21 C3 A2 64  12 C4 44 41 0D 88 0A D7  =e.,!..d..DA....
00000310: C8 F3 C7 39 8D CD 2E B5  D6 90 A5 A2 29 7F E1 84  ...9........)...
00000320: 6C EE 37 40 68 6B FD E1  0A 0D B2 15 90 94 B8 8D  l.7@hk..........
00000330: BC 59 CC 4D 9B 02 DA F5  5A 17 4F F6 C4 BB 55 BD  .Y.M....Z.O...U.
00000340: 0B A4 CF A1 0E DB 93 2F  4A C4 A0 D7 A1 A6 47 3C  ......./J.....G<
00000350: D5 65 89 1B D9 70 7E 5F  A6 1D 4B EB 94 C7 4A F2  .e...p~_..K...J.
00000360: C9 E0 1C 7D 63 6E DE 02  0F 82 02 EC C8 8C 40 96  ...}cn........@.
00000370: 08 AC FF A8 25 45 98 F6  18 B7 4D 47 DB 8B 32 3E  ....%E....MG..2>
00000380: F9 A6 A9 2C 72 E4 54 AC  DF 25 A5 25 EF AF 4A 8C  ...,r.T..%.%..J.
00000390: BC 08 47 A3 74 7B C8 04  DC 5E 9A 3B F9 62 CE 79  ..G.t{...^.;.b.y
000003A0: 15 E4 D1 69 12 1E E5 F6  BA 68 10 66 92 81 A7 F6  ...i.....h.f....
000003B0: 09 36 76 BF 17 D9 72 18  BB 19 B7 FF 28 7A 4C 03  .6v...r.....(zL.
000003C0: FC 6F 84 78 A5 12 38 18  36 5E BB 46 37 33 46 38  .o.x..8.6^.F73F8
000003D0: 35 43 34 36 31 44 31 38  30 33 30                 5C461D18030
```

The private key (encrypted by the LMK) is therefore:

```
b'S1070403RS00N0002J^c\xa3\xa3\xe5\xc7t\xf2a\xc8\xa7!=*\xdeW\xd0\x03[V.LRA\x1f\xeel\x99\xf1\x88X\x89\xbc^B\x18\x91\xde\xa8(\x88R\xe3dXf0K\x10\xb8\xb4>\xae\xc58\xfe\xa0\xd2g\xfc\xd4\xbe\xa9~\xa1\x8e\xe5\xd4\xdcW\xebsN\xf5\';1\x1b\x1bdL\xb3\x9bC\x1a\xc0Nf\xc8C\xef\xfc\xb8k\xe9R\xef\xd7M~\xdb=j\x92\x08\xe5\xa2mG\xd7\x88&\xa6>\xcd\xea\x89wh>7\xac\xc1E\xf5\x9d06\xa2\x849\xac\x01\x15\xda\xd9\xaf\x19\xfa\xae\r\x08\x90\xed\x06<`-y\xedf\x0b\xbf\x9b\xf1\x02\xa0\x89N\xc4X)w\x85\x95\x94\x96d\x16_\xf2n\x95\xcba\xfd\xab\xf2\x81\x81B\xc4\xf4\xbc\x86\x1c\x1f7\x9c\x06\xe9\xd5W\x81\xda\x8f\xc9\xeaf(6\xd7\xaf\xacS\xa9\xbda5\x12S\xd1\r=hs\x8an\xbe6\x19Xw\xda\xff\x9e\xcaV\x9d\xbc\xc2\x18\nf\x12T\xe0H+4W\t\x00\x924\xf0\xfdc\xc6\xbdx*\xd2$Y\xc2\x8a\xab\xcb\xd5wo\x0cr\x94\xb4\xd3/\xf5>\xc3\x8ca\xdc\x80/\xd1\x85\xdd\xee\xe4\xf8\x11\\\xc9\xd6\xd2f\xb7IN\x8do\xaa\xa3\xce\xf8\xb0"\xa7\xf9$,\xc4=\x89\x03\xdb\x16R\xfc\xb3\x1czPzCo\x84\x80\xf261\x16\xbbah\xfa\xe2S\x13\xf1e|\xf5\xbfi\xa9\rE\xe8k\x81\x1f\x1f\xed\xf1\x0bV\x10\xcd\xf4V\x1c\xd2}>\xac\xde\xb7C\xba\x11\xd4\xaboi\x8a\xdcV84\xea97\xd7\x02\x91d\x947\xb3\xb7\xf1\x88\xfc\'\xbe\xb0\x85F\xbe\xe3\xb5\xd43["G,e9\xca\xe7k\xe6\xca\xf7H\x9be\x97\x96\xce\xe7\x0e1[\x87\xe8FJ \xdb\x8c\xb1\x8dM6q@\xe1\xb6[\xd3\x0c\xe4\xde>\xfb\x1f\xc6 +\xd5\x9e#\x0f\xde\xa5\x08\xbdl\xee\x13\x0b\xb618\x02\xca\n\xd3\xb8zaH\x17=e\xbf,!\xc3\xa2d\x12\xc4DA\r\x88\n\xd7\xc8\xf3\xc79\x8d\xcd.\xb5\xd6\x90\xa5\xa2)\x7f\xe1\x84l\xee7@hk\xfd\xe1\n\r\xb2\x15\x90\x94\xb8\x8d\xbcY\xccM\x9b\x02\xda\xf5Z\x17O\xf6\xc4\xbbU\xbd\x0b\xa4\xcf\xa1\x0e\xdb\x93/J\xc4\xa0\xd7\xa1\xa6G<\xd5e\x89\x1b\xd9p~_\xa6\x1dK\xeb\x94\xc7J\xf2\xc9\xe0\x1c}cn\xde\x02\x0f\x82\x02\xec\xc8\x8c@\x96\x08\xac\xff\xa8%E\x98\xf6\x18\xb7MG\xdb\x8b2>\xf9\xa6\xa9,r\xe4T\xac\xdf%\xa5%\xef\xafJ\x8c\xbc\x08G\xa3t{\xc8\x04\xdc^\x9a;\xf9b\xcey\x15\xe4\xd1i\x12\x1e\xe5\xf6\xbah\x10f\x92\x81\xa7\xf6\t6v\xbf\x17\xd9r\x18\xbb\x19\xb7\xff(zL\x03\xfco\x84x\xa5\x128\x186^\xbbF73F85C461D18030'
```

Take the private key and use this in the EW (Generate Signature) command:

```
00000000: 48 45 41 44 45 57 30 36  30 31 30 31 30 30 31 32  HEADEW0601010012
00000010: 64 61 74 61 20 74 6F 20  73 69 67 6E 3B 39 39 46  data to sign;99F
00000020: 46 46 46 53 31 30 37 30  34 30 33 52 53 30 30 4E  FFFS1070403RS00N
00000030: 30 30 30 32 4A 5E 63 A3  A3 E5 C7 74 F2 61 C8 A7  0002J^c....t.a..
00000040: 21 3D 2A DE 57 D0 03 5B  56 2E 4C 52 41 1F EE 6C  !=*.W..[V.LRA..l
00000050: 99 F1 88 58 89 BC 5E 42  18 91 DE A8 28 88 52 E3  ...X..^B....(.R.
00000060: 64 58 66 30 4B 10 B8 B4  3E AE C5 38 FE A0 D2 67  dXf0K...>..8...g
00000070: FC D4 BE A9 7E A1 8E E5  D4 DC 57 EB 73 4E F5 27  ....~.....W.sN.'
00000080: 3B 31 1B 1B 64 4C B3 9B  43 1A C0 4E 66 C8 43 EF  ;1..dL..C..Nf.C.
00000090: FC B8 6B E9 52 EF D7 4D  7E DB 3D 6A 92 08 E5 A2  ..k.R..M~.=j....
000000A0: 6D 47 D7 88 26 A6 3E CD  EA 89 77 68 3E 37 AC C1  mG..&.>...wh>7..
000000B0: 45 F5 9D 30 36 A2 84 39  AC 01 15 DA D9 AF 19 FA  E..06..9........
000000C0: AE 0D 08 90 ED 06 3C 60  2D 79 ED 66 0B BF 9B F1  ......<`-y.f....
000000D0: 02 A0 89 4E C4 58 29 77  85 95 94 96 64 16 5F F2  ...N.X)w....d._.
000000E0: 6E 95 CB 61 FD AB F2 81  81 42 C4 F4 BC 86 1C 1F  n..a.....B......
000000F0: 37 9C 06 E9 D5 57 81 DA  8F C9 EA 66 28 36 D7 AF  7....W.....f(6..
00000100: AC 53 A9 BD 61 35 12 53  D1 0D 3D 68 73 8A 6E BE  .S..a5.S..=hs.n.
00000110: 36 19 58 77 DA FF 9E CA  56 9D BC C2 18 0A 66 12  6.Xw....V.....f.
00000120: 54 E0 48 2B 34 57 09 00  92 34 F0 FD 63 C6 BD 78  T.H+4W...4..c..x
00000130: 2A D2 24 59 C2 8A AB CB  D5 77 6F 0C 72 94 B4 D3  *.$Y.....wo.r...
00000140: 2F F5 3E C3 8C 61 DC 80  2F D1 85 DD EE E4 F8 11  /.>..a../.......
00000150: 5C C9 D6 D2 66 B7 49 4E  8D 6F AA A3 CE F8 B0 22  \...f.IN.o....."
00000160: A7 F9 24 2C C4 3D 89 03  DB 16 52 FC B3 1C 7A 50  ..$,.=....R...zP
00000170: 7A 43 6F 84 80 F2 36 31  16 BB 61 68 FA E2 53 13  zCo...61..ah..S.
00000180: F1 65 7C F5 BF 69 A9 0D  45 E8 6B 81 1F 1F ED F1  .e|..i..E.k.....
00000190: 0B 56 10 CD F4 56 1C D2  7D 3E AC DE B7 43 BA 11  .V...V..}>...C..
000001A0: D4 AB 6F 69 8A DC 56 38  34 EA 39 37 D7 02 91 64  ..oi..V84.97...d
000001B0: 94 37 B3 B7 F1 88 FC 27  BE B0 85 46 BE E3 B5 D4  .7.....'...F....
000001C0: 33 5B 22 47 2C 65 39 CA  E7 6B E6 CA F7 48 9B 65  3["G,e9..k...H.e
000001D0: 97 96 CE E7 0E 31 5B 87  E8 46 4A 20 DB 8C B1 8D  .....1[..FJ ....
000001E0: 4D 36 71 40 E1 B6 5B D3  0C E4 DE 3E FB 1F C6 20  M6q@..[....>...
000001F0: 2B D5 9E 23 0F DE A5 08  BD 6C EE 13 0B B6 31 38  +..#.....l....18
00000200: 02 CA 0A D3 B8 7A 61 48  17 3D 65 BF 2C 21 C3 A2  .....zaH.=e.,!..
00000210: 64 12 C4 44 41 0D 88 0A  D7 C8 F3 C7 39 8D CD 2E  d..DA.......9...
00000220: B5 D6 90 A5 A2 29 7F E1  84 6C EE 37 40 68 6B FD  .....)...l.7@hk.
00000230: E1 0A 0D B2 15 90 94 B8  8D BC 59 CC 4D 9B 02 DA  ..........Y.M...
00000240: F5 5A 17 4F F6 C4 BB 55  BD 0B A4 CF A1 0E DB 93  .Z.O...U........
00000250: 2F 4A C4 A0 D7 A1 A6 47  3C D5 65 89 1B D9 70 7E  /J.....G<.e...p~
00000260: 5F A6 1D 4B EB 94 C7 4A  F2 C9 E0 1C 7D 63 6E DE  _..K...J....}cn.
00000270: 02 0F 82 02 EC C8 8C 40  96 08 AC FF A8 25 45 98  .......@.....%E.
00000280: F6 18 B7 4D 47 DB 8B 32  3E F9 A6 A9 2C 72 E4 54  ...MG..2>...,r.T
00000290: AC DF 25 A5 25 EF AF 4A  8C BC 08 47 A3 74 7B C8  ..%.%..J...G.t{.
000002A0: 04 DC 5E 9A 3B F9 62 CE  79 15 E4 D1 69 12 1E E5  ..^.;.b.y...i...
000002B0: F6 BA 68 10 66 92 81 A7  F6 09 36 76 BF 17 D9 72  ..h.f.....6v...r
000002C0: 18 BB 19 B7 FF 28 7A 4C  03 FC 6F 84 78 A5 12 38  .....(zL..o.x..8
000002D0: 18 36 5E BB 46 37 33 46  38 35 43 34 36 31 44 31  .6^.F73F85C461D1
000002E0: 38 30 33 30                                       8030
```

EX HSM Response:

```
00000000: 48 45 41 44 45 58 30 30  30 32 35 36 68 3B 95 6E  HEADEX000256h;.n
00000010: 7A 39 8D 82 41 8D 8D 23  E7 94 20 D5 2B DD F7 BA  z9..A..#.. .+...
00000020: 43 3C A7 ED 24 93 E1 37  A0 A3 32 96 A3 56 26 0F  C<..$..7..2..V&.
00000030: 94 02 44 D7 E1 ED 87 56  AC D0 D5 5A 4E 53 AA 23  ..D....V...ZNS.#
00000040: 2E 27 8C 79 78 A3 AC 25  8F 90 A4 8B 8A C8 3F EA  .'.yx..%......?.
00000050: BB 7D 10 CB 17 68 02 0A  EA EE FC 6A 81 4E 7D 27  .}...h.....j.N}'
00000060: 09 04 22 DF B0 65 C3 1F  43 F0 6E 2F AA 94 E8 17  .."..e..C.n/....
00000070: 8F D5 34 43 0C CA E3 75  C8 06 64 72 AC CE 80 5A  ..4C...u..dr...Z
00000080: 5B 87 57 CD C3 EC 04 0E  C9 8A DB FD 83 73 F3 CC  [.W..........s..
00000090: 7A E6 BA CD 75 17 3E 32  16 CE 10 66 E2 2C 5C F9  z...u.>2...f.,\.
000000A0: 38 45 07 65 54 60 84 64  F0 E7 96 A1 B4 E1 20 D5  8E.eT`.d...... .
000000B0: 9A E3 04 7B 96 C4 C5 E7  09 B1 27 44 56 FC 36 C3  ...{......'DV.6.
000000C0: F0 A5 D9 43 16 B3 C8 78  AB 82 20 B8 81 8F DA 41  ...C...x.. ....A
000000D0: 09 5F 9E F4 F5 9E FA 5C  4D F6 FF A2 62 BB 43 60  ._.....\M...b.C`
000000E0: B2 3B E4 1D B5 DD EB CD  C5 9E 20 4E 9C B4 1C D2  .;........ N....
000000F0: 8F DC D9 93 24 E1 A4 D6  45 6C CA 71 3C F8 D0 AF  ....$...El.q<...
00000100: 39 CF E8 86 C3 CB F1 53  CC 7A A8 29              9......S.z.)
```

Signature is therefore

```
b'h;\x95nz9\x8d\x82A\x8d\x8d#\xe7\x94 \xd5+\xdd\xf7\xbaC<\xa7\xed$\x93\xe17\xa0\xa32\x96\xa3V&\x0f\x94\x02D\xd7\xe1\xed\x87V\xac\xd0\xd5ZNS\xaa#.\'\x8cyx\xa3\xac%\x8f\x90\xa4\x8b\x8a\xc8?\xea\xbb}\x10\xcb\x17h\x02\n\xea\xee\xfcj\x81N}\'\t\x04"\xdf\xb0e\xc3\x1fC\xf0n/\xaa\x94\xe8\x17\x8f\xd54C\x0c\xca\xe3u\xc8\x06dr\xac\xce\x80Z[\x87W\xcd\xc3\xec\x04\x0e\xc9\x8a\xdb\xfd\x83s\xf3\xccz\xe6\xba\xcdu\x17>2\x16\xce\x10f\xe2,\\\xf98E\x07eT`\x84d\xf0\xe7\x96\xa1\xb4\xe1 \xd5\x9a\xe3\x04{\x96\xc4\xc5\xe7\t\xb1\'DV\xfc6\xc3\xf0\xa5\xd9C\x16\xb3\xc8x\xab\x82 \xb8\x81\x8f\xdaA\t_\x9e\xf4\xf5\x9e\xfa\\M\xf6\xff\xa2b\xbbC`\xb2;\xe4\x1d\xb5\xdd\xeb\xcd\xc5\x9e N\x9c\xb4\x1c\xd2\x8f\xdc\xd9\x93$\xe1\xa4\xd6El\xcaq<\xf8\xd0\xaf9\xcf\xe8\x86\xc3\xcb\xf1S\xccz\xa8)'
```